# Number of non-negative solutions to an equation - check my work

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I tried to solve the following question and would love someone to check my work.

> Let $\displaystyle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ $100$ digits long numbers where every digit is $1$ or $2$.
>
> Find the number of non-negative solutions to the equation $\displaystyle x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6\cdot{\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}}$

**My try:**
First $\displaystyle 6\cdot{\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}}=6(10^0+10^1+...+10^{99})$.

We are told that $\forall i\in[1,4]: x_i \ \mathrm{is} \ 100 \ \mathrm{digits \ long}$, thus we can write $$x_1=\sum_{i=0}^{99}y_i\cdot{10^i} \ ; \ x_2=\sum_{i=0}^{99}z_i\cdot{10^i} \ ; \ x_3=\sum_{i=0}^{99}w_i\cdot{10^i} \ ; \ x_4=\sum_{i=0}^{99}t_i\cdot{10^i}$$
So, $$\small (y_0+z_0+w_0+t_0)10^0+(y_1+z_1+w_1+t_1)10^1+...+(y_{99}+z_{99}+w_{99}+t_{99})10^{99}=6(10^0+...+10^{99})$$
Equating coefficients we get a system of $100$ equations: $$\begin{cases}y_0+z_0+w_0+t_0=6\\ \qquad\qquad\vdots \\y_{99}+z_{99}+w_{99}+t_{99}=6\end{cases}$$
Hence, we need to find the number of non-negative solutions of the equation $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=6$ where $\forall i\in[1,4]: \ 1 \le a_i \le 2$.
Using generating function I found that there are six optional solutions, hence any of the $100$ equations has six solutions and the equations are not dependent, hence the original formula has $6^{100}$ optional solutions.

Is my reasoning correct? Is the final answer correct?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks correct to me.  Nice work.

Comment: The only addition I would make is pointing out the significance of $a_i$ being 1 or 2 leading to the equations being independent. It's a simple explanation. In your current statement, it seems as if the dependence is based on having 6 possible solutions which is not sufficient to prove independence.

Comment: @BirdKiller1989, I think that the fact that $a_i$ being 1 or 2 has nothing to do with the equations being independent. Any solution of the first equation correspond to any of the six solutions to any other equation.

Comment: @Galc127 I may have used the word "independent" too loosely. What I mean is that if $a_i$ could be greater than 2, then we can have an equation of factor $10^k$ to equal a factor $10^{k+1}$. For example, consider if $(4 + 4 + 4 + 4) 10^3$ was possible, that would force the next equation for factor $10^4$ to have the sums of $a_i$ for $10^4$ to equal 5 mod 10.

Comment: @BirdKiller1989, now it is understood! Thanks!

Comment: It’s fine. Note, though, that you didn’t need generating functions to count solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$. The sum is $4$ if each $a_k=1$, and the sum increases by $1$ each time you replace a $1$ with a $2$. Each $a_k$ has to be $1$ or $2$, so you must have exactly two $1$s and two $2$s, and there are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose which two $a_k$’s will be $2$.